# How to customize the system menu on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, system, menu-bar

I have a problem with "gnome-control-center" when I reinstalled "gnome-control-center" I lost icons from the system menu on top-right corner.
I use Ubuntu 20.04 and can't find a solution how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Is it appearing again if you open a terminal and type `gnome-control-center`?

Comment: Probably no need to ask, but did you already log out and back in, or restart the computer to see whether that fixes the issue? Also edit the title of your question. It does not reflect what you really are asking.

Comment: I rebooted the system and it didn't help.
When I entered the gnome-control-center command in a terminal, the problem is not resolved